# Is it valid practice to use GCHandle.Alloc(this)?

Tags: c#, clr

I am interfacing with a native library. The library provides Types of their internal workings, and some Types have a `void* userData`.
Because of the way the library is laid out (you can't access a specific outer type from a certain type), I need to marshal the UserData in such a way that I can access *my* data from callbacks that provide the `void* userData`.
For that I had the idea of pinning my own types on creation, to allow stable pointers.

The idea is as follows:

```cs
struct LibraryType {
    void* userData;
    void setUserData(void*);
}

delegate void LibraryFunc(void* userData); // signature of function that gets called somewhere from within the library


struct MyType : IDisposable {
    GCHandle handle;
    MyType* thisInstance;

    public MyType() {
        handle= GCHandle.Alloc(this,GCHandleType.Pinned);
        thisInstance= (MyType *)GCHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject();
        LibraryType t = ...
        t.setUserData(thisInstance);
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        thisInstance = null;
        handle.Free();
    }
}
```

Is this valid? Can `this` be passed to `GCHandle` without issues?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense because you passed in a boxed object.

Comment: Why don't you just used `Marshal.PtrToStructure`?

Comment: @shingo does that mean that whatever I am pinning is not the object I intend to pin?
How does pinning work at all then?

Comment: Yes, usually you should pin a reference object. [Pinned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.gchandletype?view=net-7.0): This prevents the garbage collector from moving the object.